# Gtk.CellRendererText makes itself really tall when I wrap it

Tags: python, gtk

I'm trying to allow wrapping of the text in a Gtk.CellRendererText but I have small problem:

[image: huge rows!]

Those rows are very large.

The only code I changed was this:

```
    cell = Gtk.CellRendererText(markup=0)
    cell.set_property("wrap_mode", Pango.WrapMode.WORD)
    cell.set_property("wrap_width", 20)
```

And that makes it wrap, but it also seemed to make this visual issue appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to remember reading something about this on a blog at planet gnome quite a while ago. From what I remember there is something to do with the height-for-width drawing model that means when wrapping is enabled GtkLabel etc request enough height to reflow the text for wrap-width even if there is more horizontal space available which leaves loads of empty space when the width is wider. There was a fix but I'm afraid I can't remember it at the moment, I'll try and find the original post later.

I've tried but I can't find the post, however having read some more I'm pretty sure this is the problem. There is some discussion related to GtkTable doing similar things at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/825173 I've a nasty feeling the fix I can't remember properly might have been to turn off wrapping. I guess it would be possible to get a notification when the column width changes and make wrap-width the correct width for that value but that's a bit of a pain.

If you can live with the column being a fixed width, set the `expand` property of the column to `False` and the `fixed-width` property to `True` then set the `wrap-width`, `width-chars` and `max-width-chars` properties of the renderer all to the same value then the text wraps without any extra space.

Comment: Oh no :( Because References are really long, this might be a massive problem

Comment: This seems to be a [known bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=653108) :-(

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hope the bug can be fixed soon though :)

Comment: I seem to have fixed it via the fixed width method and setting this when the window is resized. https://github.com/kennydude/reference-cat/commit/af79b567f6a63cf9416c14812b82063723d96271